# Function that finds the number of occurrences of each element in the input list

Tags: lisp

So I am making a program that will print me the number of occurrences of each element in the input list. So far I've managed to do it for a single symbol. (In my example for c). Result for the code below is 2.

```
(defun stejem (a L)
  (cond
   ((null L) 0)
   ((equal a (car L)) (+ 1 (stejem a (cdr L))))
   (t (stejem a (cdr L)))))

(print (stejem 'c '(a b c b b a c d)))
```

Now I am trying to upgrade it to a way that it will print the numbers of occurrences of a, b, c and d. For example output would look like this: `((a 2)(b 3)(c 2)(d 1))`.

Comment: I think you mean "single symbol". There's nothing in your function that works only on characters.

Comment: Pass an association list to the function as another argument. If the current symbol is already in the a-list, add 1 to the corresponding value. Otherwise, push a list with the symbol and `1` onto the a-list. Then call the function recursively. Finally, return the a-list.

Comment: @Barmar yes I meant symbol. Thank you for such a clear answer!

Comment: You're not being taught effective Common Lisp. Built-in: `(count 'c '(a b c b b a c d))`.

Comment: @Kaz Yes I know but I was trying to do it on my own :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. Thank you for your suggestions.

```
(defun len (l)
  (if l
    (1+ (len (cdr l)))
    0))

(defun filter (s c)
    (cond ((equal c (car s)) (cons (car s) (filter (cdr s) c)))
          ((null s) nil)
          (t (filter (remove (car s) s) c))))

(defun ponavljanje (s)
    (cond ((null s) nil)
          (t (cons (cons (car s)
                         (cons (len (filter s (car s))) nil))
                   (ponavljanje (remove (car s) s))))))

(print (ponavljanje '(a b c b b a c d)))
```